# Can svn "ignore" deleted files or delete them from repository?

Tags: svn

When I try to commit my project to svn I get the following issue

```
svn: '/var/www/sites/blabla/425/file.png' is scheduled for addition, but is missing
```

This happens because some material is deleted from the project (and I cannot use svn to delete it). Is there a way to say svn to ignore such files, or just to delete it them if they are not found ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do a `svn status`, the output will show any such files which are "missing" as a line starting with an exclamation mark:

```
!       425/file.png
```

You should write a script (in your scripting language or command line shell of choice) which parses this output, looks for lines starting with an exclamation mark, extracts the filename, and which then does a `svn revert <filename>`. This will then undo the local change to that file, allowing you to commit without problems.

**edit**: since you mentioned a php script in a comment, I suppose you are familiar with PHP scripting. In that case you can make use of the PHP function [svn_status](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-status.php).

**edit2**: if you want to delete the file from the repository, do a `svn rm --force <filename>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm actually using a similar script to add all new files: **svn status | grep ^\? | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add** . Do you think I can just replace "?" with "!" and "add" with "--force delete" ?

Comment: I've actually tried and it doesn't work. Sorry I forgot to mention I don't want to revert the file, but delete it from the repository.

Answer (score 5):

So you `svn add` the file but later on deleted it manually? Try;

```
svn rm --force file.png
```

to remove it from the SVN index.

Comment: @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez The file is deleted by a php script. So I dunno which files to remove with "svn rm" (I dunno the filename in your command). I need to automatically delete the files not found in the working copy).

Comment: There is no automatic way, you need to manually find those deleted paths and run `svn rm --force` on them.

Comment: The behavior you're asking for is "dangerous". If you accidentally delete a file from your workspace--that's a fairly destructive response.

Comment: @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez uhmm... when I commit the repository says which files are missing. Is there a way to ask svn to ignore them instead of stopping the commitment ?

Comment: @Patrick , svn can't do that since the repository is in an inconsistent state. Svn thinks file.png was added but suddenly its not there anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it is dangerous, but I can still accept to restore the older copies.

Comment: @Patrick svn as it stands can't do that since its accepted to be dangerous.

Comment: @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez I'm afraid I have to drop svn then to keep an online copy of my website. Do you have any other tip ?

Comment: Uhm, if you really really want this you can run `svn status` look for files with `!` before them and delete those files before commit, those are the `added but now non-existent` files . Still just too dangerous imho.

Comment: @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez So, if I --force delete such file from my repository, do I lose all my previous commitments of that file as well ?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command from Terminal:

```
svn revert $(svn st | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} $1=="!" && $2 !~ /\.(sql|log|tmpl)$/ {print $2}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
svn status | grep ^\! | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -L1 svn del --force
```

and if you have whitespaces in your filenames, we cannot use awk so we cut until the start of the filename (You'll probably have to edit this one: because idk if we must cut 9 characters on every system) :

```
svn status | grep ^\! | cut -c9- | sed 's/ /\\ /g'| xargs -L1 svn del --force
```

Comment: While this code/snippet may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: the only trick to know here is to use the -L1 option for xargs to limit the execution one line after another. If you don't,  you can end up overflowing the size of characters xargs can handle